# Icon selector not working with PagerSlidingTabStrips

Tags: android, pagerslidingtabstrip

I've integrated `PagerSlidingTabStrips` with `Icons` only. But I `selector` on icons are not working with `PagerSlidingTabStrips`.

*xml*

```
<PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_sliding_tab_strip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dip"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:pstsDividerColor="#FFFFA500"
    app:pstsIndicatorColor="#FFFFA500"
    app:pstsTabPaddingLeftRight="14dip"
    app:pstsUnderlineColor="#FFFFA500" />
```

Added `implements IconTabProvider` on my `ViewPager` which works perfectly.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements IconTabProvider {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    private final int[] ICONS = { R.drawable.tab_icon_zname_contacts_selector, R.drawable.tab_icon_zname_friends_selector, 
        R.drawable.tab_icon_zname_call_log_selector };

    @Override
    public int getPageIconResId(int position) {
        return ICONS[position];
    }
}
```

*iconSelector*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_icon_zname_call_log_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_icon_zname_call_log" android:state_selected="false"/>

</selector>
```

*How to make icon selector work with `PagerSlidingTabStrips`*? I wanted icon with Orange color when that tab is selected but it's returning grey one only no matter what.

[image: Result I'm getting]

Comment: How did you add icons instead of text in the pagerslidingtabStrip ?

Comment: Where did you find `IconTabProvider`? It was not in the `PagerSlidingTabStrip.java`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've found fix for `Icon_Selector` for `PagerSlidingTabStrips` within it's closed issues.

Modify `PagerSlidingTabStrips.java` and add following code

```
  private int currentPageSelected = 0; //Fix : ICON SELECTOR
```

Append on `NotifyDataSetChanged` method inside `OnGlobalLayoutListener`

```
  currentPosition = pager.getCurrentItem();
  tabsContainer.getChildAt(currentPosition).setSelected(true); //ADDED THESE
  scrollToChild(currentPosition, 0);
```

Modified the `onPageSelected()`:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
tabsContainer.getChildAt(currentPageSelected).setSelected(false);
currentPageSelected = position;
tabsContainer.getChildAt(position).setSelected(true);

if (delegatePageListener != null) {
     delegatePageListener.onPageSelected(position
 }
}
```

*IconSelector*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_icon_zname_call_log_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_icon_zname_call_log_selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_icon_zname_call_log"/>
  </selector>
```

[image: PagerSlidingTabStrips with Icon Selector]

PagerSlidingTabStrips.java

```
import java.util.Locale;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.netdoers.zname.R;

public class PagerSlidingTabStrip extends HorizontalScrollView {

    public interface IconTabProvider {
        public int getPageIconResId(int position);
    }

    // @formatter:off
    private static final int[] ATTRS = new int[] {
        android.R.attr.textSize,
        android.R.attr.textColor
    };
    // @formatter:on

    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams defaultTabLayoutParams;
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams expandedTabLayoutParams;

    private final PageListener pageListener = new PageListener();
    public OnPageChangeListener delegatePageListener;

    private LinearLayout tabsContainer;
    private ViewPager pager;

    private int tabCount;

    private int currentPosition = 0;
    private float currentPositionOffset = 0f;

    private Paint rectPaint;
    private Paint dividerPaint;

    private int currentPageSelected = 0; //Fix : ICON SELECTOR

    private int indicatorColor = 0xFF666666;
    private int underlineColor = 0x1A000000;
    private int dividerColor = 0x1A000000;

    private boolean shouldExpand = false;
    private boolean textAllCaps = true;

    private int scrollOffset = 52;
    private int indicatorHeight = 8;
    private int underlineHeight = 2;
    private int dividerPadding = 12;
    private int tabPadding = 24;
    private int dividerWidth = 1;

    private int tabTextSize = 12;
    private int tabTextColor = 0xFF666666;
    private Typeface tabTypeface = null;
    private int tabTypefaceStyle = Typeface.BOLD;

    private int lastScrollX = 0;

    private int tabBackgroundResId = R.drawable.background_tab;

    private Locale locale;

    public PagerSlidingTabStrip(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public PagerSlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public PagerSlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        setFillViewport(true);
        setWillNotDraw(false);

        tabsContainer = new LinearLayout(context);
        tabsContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        tabsContainer.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        addView(tabsContainer);

        DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        scrollOffset = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, scrollOffset, dm);
        indicatorHeight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, indicatorHeight, dm);
        underlineHeight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, underlineHeight, dm);
        dividerPadding = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dividerPadding, dm);
        tabPadding = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, tabPadding, dm);
        dividerWidth = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dividerWidth, dm);
        tabTextSize = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, tabTextSize, dm);

        // get system attrs (android:textSize and android:textColor)

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, ATTRS);

        tabTextSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(0, tabTextSize);
        tabTextColor = a.getColor(1, tabTextColor);

        a.recycle();

        // get custom attrs

        a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip);

        indicatorColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsIndicatorColor, indicatorColor);
        underlineColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsUnderlineColor, underlineColor);
        dividerColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsDividerColor, dividerColor);
        indicatorHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsIndicatorHeight, indicatorHeight);
        underlineHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsUnderlineHeight, underlineHeight);
        dividerPadding = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsDividerPadding, dividerPadding);
        tabPadding = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsTabPaddingLeftRight, tabPadding);
        tabBackgroundResId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsTabBackground, tabBackgroundResId);
        shouldExpand = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsShouldExpand, shouldExpand);
        scrollOffset = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsScrollOffset, scrollOffset);
        textAllCaps = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsTextAllCaps, textAllCaps);

        a.recycle();

        rectPaint = new Paint();
        rectPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        rectPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        dividerPaint = new Paint();
        dividerPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        dividerPaint.setStrokeWidth(dividerWidth);

        defaultTabLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        expandedTabLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);

        if (locale == null) {
            locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
        }
    }

    public void setViewPager(ViewPager pager) {
        this.pager = pager;

        if (pager.getAdapter() == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ViewPager does not have adapter instance.");
        }

        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageListener);

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setOnPageChangeListener(OnPageChangeListener listener) {
        this.delegatePageListener = listener;
    }

    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {

        tabsContainer.removeAllViews();

        tabCount = pager.getAdapter().getCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {

            if (pager.getAdapter() instanceof IconTabProvider) {
                addIconTab(i, ((IconTabProvider) pager.getAdapter()).getPageIconResId(i));
            } else {
                addTextTab(i, pager.getAdapter().getPageTitle(i).toString());
            }

        }

        updateTabStyles();

        getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }

                currentPosition = pager.getCurrentItem();
                tabsContainer.getChildAt(currentPosition).setSelected(true);//Fix : ICON SELECTOR
                scrollToChild(currentPosition, 0);
            }
        });

    }

    private void addTextTab(final int position, String title) {

        TextView tab = new TextView(getContext());
        tab.setText(title);
        tab.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tab.setSingleLine();

        addTab(position, tab);
    }

    private void addIconTab(final int position, int resId) {

        ImageButton tab = new ImageButton(getContext());
        tab.setImageResource(resId);

        addTab(position, tab);

    }

    private void addTab(final int position, View tab) {
        tab.setFocusable(true);
        tab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(position);
            }
        });

        tab.setPadding(tabPadding, 0, tabPadding, 0);
        tabsContainer.addView(tab, position, shouldExpand ? expandedTabLayoutParams : defaultTabLayoutParams);
    }

    private void updateTabStyles() {

        for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {

            View v = tabsContainer.getChildAt(i);

            v.setBackgroundResource(tabBackgroundResId);

            if (v instanceof TextView) {

                TextView tab = (TextView) v;
                tab.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, tabTextSize);
                tab.setTypeface(tabTypeface, tabTypefaceStyle);
                tab.setTextColor(tabTextColor);

                // setAllCaps() is only available from API 14, so the upper case is made manually if we are on a
                // pre-ICS-build
                if (textAllCaps) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                        tab.setAllCaps(true);
                    } else {
                        tab.setText(tab.getText().toString().toUpperCase(locale));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void scrollToChild(int position, int offset) {

        if (tabCount == 0) {
            return;
        }

        int newScrollX = tabsContainer.getChildAt(position).getLeft() + offset;

        if (position > 0 || offset > 0) {
            newScrollX -= scrollOffset;
        }

        if (newScrollX != lastScrollX) {
            lastScrollX = newScrollX;
            scrollTo(newScrollX, 0);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (isInEditMode() || tabCount == 0) {
            return;
        }

        final int height = getHeight();

        // draw indicator line

        rectPaint.setColor(indicatorColor);

        // default: line below current tab
        View currentTab = tabsContainer.getChildAt(currentPosition);
        float lineLeft = currentTab.getLeft();
        float lineRight = currentTab.getRight();

        // if there is an offset, start interpolating left and right coordinates between current and next tab
        if (currentPositionOffset > 0f && currentPosition < tabCount - 1) {

            View nextTab = tabsContainer.getChildAt(currentPosition + 1);
            final float nextTabLeft = nextTab.getLeft();
            final float nextTabRight = nextTab.getRight();

            lineLeft = (currentPositionOffset * nextTabLeft + (1f - currentPositionOffset) * lineLeft);
            lineRight = (currentPositionOffset * nextTabRight + (1f - currentPositionOffset) * lineRight);
        }

        canvas.drawRect(lineLeft, height - indicatorHeight, lineRight, height, rectPaint);

        // draw underline

        rectPaint.setColor(underlineColor);
        canvas.drawRect(0, height - underlineHeight, tabsContainer.getWidth(), height, rectPaint);

        // draw divider

        dividerPaint.setColor(dividerColor);
        for (int i = 0; i < tabCount - 1; i++) {
            View tab = tabsContainer.getChildAt(i);
            canvas.drawLine(tab.getRight(), dividerPadding, tab.getRight(), height - dividerPadding, dividerPaint);
        }
    }

    private class PageListener implements OnPageChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            currentPosition = position;
            currentPositionOffset = positionOffset;

            scrollToChild(position, (int) (positionOffset * tabsContainer.getChildAt(position).getWidth()));

            invalidate();

            if (delegatePageListener != null) {
                delegatePageListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                scrollToChild(pager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
            }

            if (delegatePageListener != null) {
                delegatePageListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            /**
             * Fix : ICON SELECTOR
             */
            tabsContainer.getChildAt(currentPageSelected).setSelected(false);
            currentPageSelected = position;
            tabsContainer.getChildAt(position).setSelected(true);
            /**
             * Fix : ICON SELECTOR
             */

            if (delegatePageListener != null) {
                delegatePageListener.onPageSelected(position);
            }
        }

    }

    public void setIndicatorColor(int indicatorColor) {
        this.indicatorColor = indicatorColor;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setIndicatorColorResource(int resId) {
        this.indicatorColor = getResources().getColor(resId);
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getIndicatorColor() {
        return this.indicatorColor;
    }

    public void setIndicatorHeight(int indicatorLineHeightPx) {
        this.indicatorHeight = indicatorLineHeightPx;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getIndicatorHeight() {
        return indicatorHeight;
    }

    public void setUnderlineColor(int underlineColor) {
        this.underlineColor = underlineColor;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setUnderlineColorResource(int resId) {
        this.underlineColor = getResources().getColor(resId);
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getUnderlineColor() {
        return underlineColor;
    }

    public void setDividerColor(int dividerColor) {
        this.dividerColor = dividerColor;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setDividerColorResource(int resId) {
        this.dividerColor = getResources().getColor(resId);
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getDividerColor() {
        return dividerColor;
    }

    public void setUnderlineHeight(int underlineHeightPx) {
        this.underlineHeight = underlineHeightPx;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getUnderlineHeight() {
        return underlineHeight;
    }

    public void setDividerPadding(int dividerPaddingPx) {
        this.dividerPadding = dividerPaddingPx;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getDividerPadding() {
        return dividerPadding;
    }

    public void setScrollOffset(int scrollOffsetPx) {
        this.scrollOffset = scrollOffsetPx;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getScrollOffset() {
        return scrollOffset;
    }

    public void setShouldExpand(boolean shouldExpand) {
        this.shouldExpand = shouldExpand;
        requestLayout();
    }

    public boolean getShouldExpand() {
        return shouldExpand;
    }

    public boolean isTextAllCaps() {
        return textAllCaps;
    }

    public void setAllCaps(boolean textAllCaps) {
        this.textAllCaps = textAllCaps;
    }

    public void setTextSize(int textSizePx) {
        this.tabTextSize = textSizePx;
        updateTabStyles();
    }

    public int getTextSize() {
        return tabTextSize;
    }

    public void setTextColor(int textColor) {
        this.tabTextColor = textColor;
        updateTabStyles();
    }

    public void setTextColorResource(int resId) {
        this.tabTextColor = getResources().getColor(resId);
        updateTabStyles();
    }

    public int getTextColor() {
        return tabTextColor;
    }

    public void setTypeface(Typeface typeface, int style) {
        this.tabTypeface = typeface;
        this.tabTypefaceStyle = style;
        updateTabStyles();
    }

    public void setTabBackground(int resId) {
        this.tabBackgroundResId = resId;
    }

    public int getTabBackground() {
        return tabBackgroundResId;
    }

    public void setTabPaddingLeftRight(int paddingPx) {
        this.tabPadding = paddingPx;
        updateTabStyles();
    }

    public int getTabPaddingLeftRight() {
        return tabPadding;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        SavedState savedState = (SavedState) state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState.getSuperState());
        currentPosition = savedState.currentPosition;
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        SavedState savedState = new SavedState(superState);
        savedState.currentPosition = currentPosition;
        return savedState;
    }

    static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
        int currentPosition;

        public SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
            super(superState);
        }

        private SavedState(Parcel in) {
            super(in);
            currentPosition = in.readInt();
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
            dest.writeInt(currentPosition);
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>() {
            @Override
            public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new SavedState(in);
            }

            @Override
            public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                return new SavedState[size];
            }
        };
    }

}
```

ViewPagerAdapter.java which we need to supply to ViewPager

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import com.netdoers.zname.R;
import com.netdoers.zname.utils.PagerSlidingTabStrip.IconTabProvider;

/**
 * @author Vikalp Patel (vikalppatelce@yahoo.com)
 * @category Ui Helper
 * 
 */
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
/**
 * PAGERSLIDINGTABSTIPS 
 */
implements IconTabProvider 
{
    // Declare the number of ViewPager pages
//  final int PAGE_COUNT = 5;
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;

    /**
     * PAGERSLIDINGTABSTRIPS
     */
    private final int[] ICONS = { R.drawable.tab_icon_zname_contact_selector, R.drawable.tab_icon_zname_friends_selector, 
            R.drawable.tab_icon_zname_call_log_selector };
    /**
     * SLIDINGTABLAYOUT
     */
    /*private int[] imageResId = {
            R.drawable.tab_icon_zname_contact_selector,
            R.drawable.tab_icon_zname_friends_selector,
            R.drawable.tab_icon_zname_call_log_selected
    };

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Drawable image = Zname.getApplication().getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(imageResId[position]);
        image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
        SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" ");
        ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
        sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return sb;
    }*/
    /**
     * SLIDINGTABLAYOUT
     */

    /**
     * @param fm
     */
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter#getItem(int)
     */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int item) {
        switch (item) {

            // Open HomeFragment.java
        case 0:
            ContactsFragment homeFragment = new ContactsFragment();
            return homeFragment;
            // Open PlaceOrderFragment.java
        case 1:
            GroupsFragment groupsFragment = new GroupsFragment();
            return groupsFragment;
        case 2:
            CallLogsFragment callLogsFragment = new CallLogsFragment();
            return callLogsFragment;
            }
        return null;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getCount()
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    /**
     * PAGERSLIDINGTABSTRIPS 
     */
    @Override
    public int getPageIconResId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ICONS[position];
    }

}
```

Comment: Had a propblem with the SlidingTabsColorFragment, I only updated the onPageSelected in a similar fashion and everything worked as intended.

Comment: This looks amazing, but can't get it to work. There is no `onNotifyDataSetChanged`, did you mean `notifyDataSetChanged()`? Probably. And where do you insert that code? I have it right after `tabsContainer.removeAllViews();`. Nothing works though. I hooked up my drawables selector file like this `custom:pstsTabBackground="@drawable/tabs_selector"`, but nothing. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: can you post complete example please i am finding difficulties in implementing this functionality

Comment: @Dimitri : I've posted whole implementation of PagerSlidingStrips & ViewPagerAdapter.

Comment: Let me Tell you One this.. You are God Damn Awesome Man... StackOverFlow Should Award you with a Special Ass saving Medal

Comment: @AsadMehmood Haha Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

My hard way to do that...

```
// Give the PagerSlidingTabStrip the ViewPager
tabsStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
// Attach the view pager to the tab strip
tabsStrip.setViewPager(mViewPager);

Field field = null;
try {
    field = PagerSlidingTabStrip.class.getDeclaredField("tabsContainer");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    LinearLayout tabsContainer = (LinearLayout) field.get(tabsStrip);
    tabsContainer.getChildAt(0).setSelected(true);

} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

tabsStrip.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    private int currentPageSelected = 0;

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        Log.v("onPageSelected", tabsStrip.getClass().toString());

        Field field = null;
        try {
            field = PagerSlidingTabStrip.class.getDeclaredField("tabsContainer");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            LinearLayout tabsContainer = (LinearLayout) field.get(tabsStrip);
            tabsContainer.getChildAt(currentPageSelected).setSelected(false);
            currentPageSelected = position;
            tabsContainer.getChildAt(position).setSelected(true);

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Good work (Y). Can you please tell me how to add text also with these icons?

Answer (score 1):

> Just add **app:pstsTabSwitch="true"** to PagerSlidingTabStrip:

```
                    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    app:pstsIndicatorColor="#2F041F"
                    app:pstsIndicatorHeight="2dp"
                    app:pstsTabPaddingLeftRight="14dp"
                    app:pstsTabSwitch="true"/>
```

> My adapter:

```
SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements PagerSlidingTabStrip.IconTabProvider {

private int TAB_ICONS[] = {R.drawable.io_logo, R.drawable.ic_chat_tab_unactive};
private final int[] SWITCH_ICONS = { R.drawable.tab_one, R.drawable.tab_two};

public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return TAB_ICONS.length;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if(position == 0){
        return new SwipeFragment();
    } else {
        return new ConversationsFragment();
    }
}


@Override
public int getPageIconResId(int position) {
    return SWITCH_ICONS[position];
}
```

}

> My selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/io_title" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/io_logo"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/io_logo"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/io_title" />
</selector>
```